# CRM Account SDK Update - Object address not found on party or party is marked as non-emailable

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-2016

We are experiencing an issue with our customized code when updating certain Account entities.  We are using CRM 2016 On-Premise, using a .Net application and CRM SDK to load records into the system.  The following describes the scenario in which we see the errors:

•   We have an Account record that exists in our CRM instance.

•   Then,    using a QueryExpression, we retrieve the Account record.

•   Next, we    do a OrganizationService Update on the record.

•   This throws an    Exception

(System.ServiceModel.FaultException), with the Message = “Object address not found on party or party is marked as non-emailable”

The confusing things is that the Update is not kicking off any Processes, we’re not doing an email/bulk-email on the record, or any other processing that should involve the email.  This doesn’t happen on all account records, only a tiny percentage of them (< 0.5%).
So the main question is, how can a simple Retrieve/Update on an Account give that type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Account entity has fields DoNotEMail and DoNotBulkEMail try setting them to Do Not Allow when you update an account. Also match current values for these fields for the account that are updated successfully vs the account that fails.